# Apache doesn't start on Snow Leopard using Terminal but works using Web Sharing (System Preferences)

Tags: apache, osx-snow-leopard

I am using the default Apache installation that comes with Snow Leopard and I have some things installed like MySQL, Rudix (Unix ports and packages) and Xcode.

When I type:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

I receive this output:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _apr_dir_open$INODE64
  Referenced from: /usr/local/sbin/httpd
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
 in /usr/local/sbin/httpd
/usr/local/sbin/apachectl: line 78:  2023 Trace/BPT trap          $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

I don't know if it's related but my `.bash_profile` has this line (I typed it because `import MySQLdb` was not working in Python):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

If I tick *Web Sharing* using *System Preferences* the Apache starts and work, but I wan't to start it using the terminal, maybe I am forgot to pass important arguments to the `apachectl` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Web Sharing` option of `System Preferences` enables the Apple-supplied Apache.  Its `apachectl` is `/usr/sbin/apachectl`.  You appear to have installed another version of Apache in `/usr/local`; note the `/usr/local/sbin/apachectl` path.  So you are *not* using the Apple-supplied Apache installation when you are running from the terminal and the version you are using appears to not have been installed correctly.  One way to ensure you are using the Apple-supplied Apache is to specify the full path:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start
```

Comment: You were right, I used your suggested command and I run in another problem with ULIMIT_MAX_FILES but already solved at internet on http://notfornoone.com/2010/11/snow-leopard-10-6-5-and-apachectl/ Thanks!